# Has any way to get the dom.style changed hook,without async?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We know,css `animation/transition` was not work with `display: block`&`display: none`;
So I try to use

```
someDom.style.transition = '0.3s'
someDom.style.display='block'
someDom.style.opacity=1
```

to play an animation as `fadeIn`.
But still not work , because it run too fast.
I know `setTimeout` will works well this time, but because of the javaScript event loop , I don't want it became an async event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would solve your problem

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

item.style.display = 'block';
item.classList.add('fadeIn');
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

.item.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you solve this demand ! But I will keep this question open because I want to find a way to get the style changed hook